# Minimal Continuous Maps in Topological Space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**Definition:** A nonempty open set U of X is said to be a ***minimal open*** set if
and only if any open set which is contained in U is ∅ or U.

**Definition:** A nonempty open set U of X is said to be a
***maximal open*** set if any open set which contains U is X or U.

**Definition:** A proper nonempty closed subset F of X is said to be a ***minimal closed*** set if any closed
set which is contained in F is ∅ or F.

**Definition:** A proper nonempty closed subset F of X is said to
be a ***maximal closed*** set if any closed set which contains F is X or F.

**Note**: Complement of a minimal open set is maximal closed set.

**Definition:** Let X and Y be topological spaces. A map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is called ***minimal continuous*** if $f^{-1}(M)$ is an open set in X for every minimal open set M in Y.

**Question:** Let X and Y be the
topological spaces. A map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is
minimal continuous if and only if the inverse
image of each maximal closed set in Y is a
closed set in X.

**My Attempt**: $(\implies)$ Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a minimal continuous map. That is, $f^{-1}(M)\in\tau_{X}$ for every minimal open set $M\in Y$. We have that $Y-M$ is maximal closed set because the complement of a minimal open set is maximal closed set.. We need to show that $f^{-1}(Y-M)\in\kappa_{X}$ or $f^{-1}(Y-M)=X-f^{-1}(M)$ which is closed in $X$ since $f^{-1}(M)\in\tau_{X}$. Bu how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That $f^{-1}[Y\setminus M]=X\setminus f^{-1}[M]$ is basic elementary set theory. Just show that each side is a subset of the other. If $x\in X\setminus f^{-1}[M]$, for instance, then $f(x)\notin M$, so $f(x)\in Y\setminus M$, and therefore $x\in f^{-1}[Y\setminus M]$. Now just prove the opposite inclusion.

Comment: Thank you so much for reminding the basic theory :)

Comment: @Salih: You’re welcome.